# Build TListView programmatically not using livebindings

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have a cross platform app which contains a TFDMemtable(FireDAC).

My question is, how would one manually build a TListView from the records in this table?

The table I have contains a list of male forenames in alphabetical order.

e.g. Adam, Anthony, Alan, Brian, Bill, Bob, Ben, Charlie, Craig, Christopher, Colin and so on.

I want the listview to include groupings for the names, so A,B,C etc.

I have the following so far:

```
procedure BuildNameList;
var Litem : TListViewItem;
c : Char;
begin
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  try
   ListView1.ClearItems;

  for c := 'A' to 'Z' do
  begin
    with ListView1.Items.Add do
    begin
      Text := char(c);
      Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Header;
    end;

  with dmod.tableNames do
  begin
    First;
   while not Eof do
    begin
      Litem := ListView1.Items.Add;         
      Litem.Text := dmod.tableNames.FieldByName('ForeName').AsString;
      Next;
    end;
  end;
  end;
  finally
    ListView1.EndUpdate;
end;
```

The above code doesn't give me the result I'm after, what happens is I get every name duplicated under every letter group(A-Z).

Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please don't use with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your logic somewhat to add first the header, and then the names under that header, and then the next header and set of names. Here's a full test app that demonstrates. You'll need to drop a FMX TListView and a TClientDataSet on your form and connect up the FormCreate event to see it work. (Note that the index is needed on the ClientDataSet in order to ensure the names are in the proper order; if they're not alphabetized, the code won't work, because it won't find the data as needed to add to the section.)

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.ListView.Types, Data.DB,
  Datasnap.DBClient, FMX.ListView;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    CDS: TClientDataSet;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure BuildNameList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm3.BuildNameList;
var
  Item: TListViewItem;
  Ch: Char;
begin
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  CDS.First;
  try
    ListView1.ClearItems;
    for Ch := 'A' to 'Z' do
    begin
      Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
      Item.Text := Ch;
      Item.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Header;

      while (CDS.FieldByName('SurName').AsString[1] = Ch) and (not CDS.Eof) do
      begin
        Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
        Item.Text := CDS.FieldByName('SurName').AsString + ', ' +
                     CDS.FieldByName('ForeName').AsString;

        CDS.Next;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    ListView1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Create some test data
  CDS.FieldDefs.Add('ForeName', ftString, 20);
  CDS.FieldDefs.Add('SurName', ftString, 30);
  CDS.CreateDataSet;
  CDS.Open;
  CDS.AppendRecord(['John', 'Smith']);
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Jane', 'Doe']);
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Ralph', 'Richards']);
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Fred', 'Fredericks']);
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Sam', 'Samuels']);
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Walter', 'Williams']);
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Ann', 'Anderson']);
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Bob', 'Barnes']);

  // Index it to put it in alphabetical order
  CDS.IndexDefs.Add('Names', 'SurName;ForeName', []);
  CDS.IndexName := 'Names';
  BuildNameList;
end;

end.
```

Here's a screenshot of a center section of that sample app's ListView, so you can see the results:

[image: ListView displaying alpha list with section headers]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't appear to work, it only builds the groups(A,B,C etc) and not the name fields within the groups. Your code does seem a lot clearer compared to what I did, so I'll see where else I can go from here and hopefully achieve my goal!

Comment: @6String_Coder: See my updated sample code. It shows that it works properly.

Comment: I can get it to work on Windows but not Android or iOS, the listview remains empty.

Comment: I can't help you with that; I answered the question you asked, which was how to add the listview items correctly, and demonstrated how to do so. You'll have to use the debugger to figure out why it won't work for you on those other OSes. (You do know there's an [example in the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3A_Using_ListBox_Components_to_Display_a_Table_View_%28iOS_and_Android%29) that shows how to do this with a `ListBox` instead of a `ListView` that works on both Android and iOS?)

Comment: Thats fine, you have been more than helpful to me. I wasn't ware of that documentation, Il take a look now. Many thanks again.